# Can one represent indexable signatures in io-ts

Tags: typescript

Can one represent [indexable signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) in [io-ts](https://github.com/gcanti/io-ts/)?

Comment: You probably looking for `t.record`

Answer (score 3):

As @aquz said, you're looking for `t.record` and you may find `t.intersection` helpful to get objects with required and additional/indexable properties.

```
interface NumberDictionary {
    requiredProperty: number;
    [index: string]: number; // additional properties 
}
```

Here's a CodeSandbox with an example.
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-swirles-ixp8q